# how to filter text according to a large number of possible values of a LIKE operator in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like, case-when, sql-function

**EDIT: I changed my example a bit because it was incorrect and misleading. Here is a more correct one (I hope so).** 
This is a complex problem to explain, so I'll try to be as clear as I can. 
I have a CASE that returns a value according to a text filter by means of the LIKE operator.
I need to generate 1 column (class_of_event) with N possible values that classify one given string in N possible categories.
This set of values searched by the LIKE operator will be used again and again in the script, and will be update occasionally.
The script is more or less like this:

```
SELECT
event,
CASE
  WHEN
    event LIKE '%MURDER%' or
    event LIKE '%KILL%' or
    ... --and so on with many other possible values...
    event LIKE '%WAR%'
  THEN 'VIOLENCE'
  WHEN
    event LIKE '%MARRIAGE%' or
    event LIKE '%MARRIED%' or
    ... --and so on with many other possible values...
    event LIKE '%WIFE%'
  THEN 'RELATIONSHIP'
  ELSE NULL 
  END class_of_event
FROM TABLE history_facts
```

<del>I know I can use the pipe | instead of the OR operator, thus writing</del>

```
CASE WHEN event LIKE '%MARRIAGE%|%MARRIED%|%WIFE%' THEN 'RELATIONSHIP' ELSE null END class_of_event
```

<del>instead of the long list of OR operators. 


Anyway this could turn out in a VERY LONG string, because I could be willing to enlarge the set of values to be looked for.</del> 


ALSO, this set of values will be used again in the (long) script, and it will be a problem if one day I'll have to rewrite them all coherently.
So I tried putting these values in the return value of a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION relationship_event()
  RETURNS text AS
$$SELECT text '%MARRIAGE%|%MARRIED%|%WIFE%'$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

and then using the following:

```
CASE WHEN event LIKE relationship_event() THEN 'RELATIONSHIP' ELSE null END class_of_event
```

This seemed a good solution because I could just define or update the function once at the beginning of the script and then use it everywhere I needed it.
The problem is that this method performs quite well in some cases and horribly in other cases.

So, is there a way to: 
1) write a synthetic version of `event LIKE 'a' OR event LIKE 'b' OR event LIKE 'c' OR...` 
2) and store the strings I am looking for in some "global variable" that I can rewrite only once and re-use everywhere in the script?

Thanks everybody, this is driving me crazy.
I think I can do this easily with SAS or Python, but can't achieve it on POSTGRESQL

Comment: "I know I can use the pipe".  I didn't know that.  The pipe is supported in regular expressions, not in like patterns.

Comment: You can't have two columns with the name `class_of_event` to begin with

Comment: you all are right, I wrote this as an example changing the original code to make it simpler but I ended up making a mess

Answer (score 3):

> *I know I can use the pipe | instead of the OR operator, thus writing*

No, you can not. LIKE does not support a pipe as an "or" operator.

You can simplify the expressions using an array:

```
SELECT event,
       CASE
         WHEN event ilike any (array['%MURDER%','%KILL%','%WAR%']) 
           then 'VIOLENCE'
         WHEN event ilike any (array['%MARRIAGE%','%MARRIED%','%WIFE%']) 
           then 'RELATIONSHIP' 
       END as class_of_event,
class_of_event
FROM history_facts;
```

You can put this into a function:

```
create or replace function map_event(p_input text)
  returns text
as
$$
  select CASE
           WHEN event ilike any (array['%MURDER%','%KILL%','%WAR%']) 
             then 'VIOLENCE'
           WHEN ilike any (array['%MARRIAGE%','%MARRIED%','%WIFE%']) 
             then 'RELATIONSHIP' 
         END;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then you just need to call the function, rather having the CASE expression:

```
select event, 
       map_event(event) as class_of_event
from history_facts;
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the corrections. Since my example was badly written, I think I misled you. I don't actually need to generate 2 columns (class_of_violence and class_of_relationship) but 1 only column with 2 possible values that classify one given string in 2 possible categories.

Comment: @AlessioOrlandi then combine the two CASE expressions into one. See my edit